# Dynamic Gridview in Dynamic Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, tabs, android-relativelayout

Im trying to add a dynamically generated gridView to a dynamically generated RelativeLayout, and do that for several tabs. The code is working, but **images appear to be misplaced**. What im I doing wrong?

```
public View createTabContent(String tag)
{
ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(MainHolder);
android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    layout.setId(tab_id);
            GridView dynGrid = new GridView(ManageRooms.this);
            dynGrid.setId(someID);
            gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
                    ...

customGridAdapter = 
new CustomGridViewAdapter(ManageRooms.this, R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);

dynGrid.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
layout.addView(dynGrid);
return layout;
}
```

row_grid.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/nfc" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Misplaced Images]
Should be fairly easy to fix, but cant find any solution. Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this: You need to tell the GridView to fit the columns:

```
dynGrid.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

dynGrid.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
dynGrid.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
dynGrid.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
dynGrid.setColumnWidth(dpToPx(60));

private int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round((float) dp * density);
}
```

Would be easier to define the GridView in XML and inflate here instead, though.

Answer (score -1):

you have to give the grid view `column count`, 
try this in your code:

```
gridView.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
```

it will automatically align the items depends upon the screen size.